# How come my array doesnt print out my index? C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I just started out with arrays and it is AMAZING!

One small thing though, how come my for loop isnt printing out the whole index or rather the value of the index one by one, but instead only prints out the last one?

[image]

Here is my code if you are having some issues with viewing the image!

```
namespace Arrays
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int[] numbers = new int[5];


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numbers[0] = 12;
            numbers[1] = 10;
            numbers[2] = 25;
            numbers[3] = 10;
            numbers[4] = 15;
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)

            displayArrays.Text = numbers[i].ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are just assigning value each time. Change

```
displayArrays.Text = numbers[i].ToString();
```

To

```
displayArrays.Text += numbers[i].ToString();
```

Or if separator is needed:

```
displayArrays.Text += numbers[i].ToString() + ", "; // But need to worry about trailling separator.
```

If you want the index, then `i` represents your current index. `numbers[i]` represents `array` value at index `i`.

Comment: Oh okay! So what I am essentially doing is (+=) adding more values from the array to the index?

Comment: @Alexander. Matt `displayArrays.Text` is another field (or as you call index). If you use simple `=` then it just assigns new value. `+=` translates into `displayArrays.Text = displayArrays.Text + numbers[i].ToString() + ", ";`. That is - updating current value.

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense now! Thank you! @DovydasSopa

Answer (score 1):

Mostly other answers answered what you need, you could simplify a bit with this one liner.

Remove `for` loop *completely* and place this logic.

```
displayArrays.Text = string.Join(",", numbers);
```

Comment: @HariPrasad im actually going to loop through 26.000 lines of text later on so wouldnt I need the for loop then?

Comment: Depends on your case, if you just want to display numbers then you don't need any loop. Additionally if you are performing any other logic may be you need it, difficult to comment unless I see complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        displayArrays.Text += ", " + numbers[i].ToString();
```